# How to copy a background in ppt with ppt api?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, powerpoint, msdn

Problem Description: My ppt presentation have 4 slides, slide 1 & 2 has background(Format Background), slide 3 & 4 hasn't background. I want to copy slide 1's background to slide 3 & 4. I can use the format painter to finish in powerpoint, that good. But I need to do this with C/C++ code in VS.

And I have had a look on MSDS this few days and still haven't any progress.

Pls visit:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff746522.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff744967.aspx

I have try the PickUp methord and Apply methord, doesn't work.

Code:
Object ShapeRange = pptSlide2.Background.PickUp(); // have error, I don't why.

Pls help.
thx!